# Declare new type in drools that extends a class with generic

Tags: java, drools

I have a java class that looks like this (with getters and setters of course):

```
public class DynamicTransaction<T> implements Serializable {
    private HeaderDTO header;
    private T body;
}
```

In Drools, I want to declare specific transactions that extend this class. So I'd like to do someting like this:

```
declare ShopTransaction extends DynamicTransaction<ShopBody>

end

declare ShopBody
    name: String
    modDate: String
    dailyIdx: int
end
```

The problem is, that I get this exception:

```
[ERR 102] Line 15:39 mismatched input '<'
```

So my question is: Is it even possible to do this type of inheritance in Drools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drools hasn't been extended to manage generics.

You need to write a Java class

```
public class ShopTransaction extends DynamicTransaction<ShopBody>
```

and then you are good to go for writing your rules with `ShopTransaction` as a pattern.